# DFT Calculations, Atomic Ionization Potentials -- Which Exchange-Correlation Functional to Use, to Preserve Koopmans Theorem?

Tags: physical-chemistry, atoms, density-functional-theory, ionization-energy

I have a program which can perform density-functional calculations for atoms, given a density functional.

Of course the simplest form of exchange potential to use is one relevant for a uniform electron gas (i.e. the original Kohn-Sham exchange, proportional to $n_e^{1/3}$). A good correlation functional is also available. However when I performed calculations for some atoms the energy of the highest occupied orbital differs greatly from the ionization potential (off by a few eVs!).

That the energy of the highest occupied orbital equals the ionisation potential of the neutral atom is known as [Koopmans' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koopmans'_theorem). I get a feeling from the literature that DFT can be quite accurate. So what's wrong?

Interestingly when I use the Slater exchange functional, coupled with a correction suggested by Skillman (i.e. replacing the potential by $1/r$ when the overall potential drops below that value), the results improve significantly. (See the book "Atomic Structure Calculations" by Herman Skillman). Well, maybe I should follow this recipe, but it seems the procedure is quite ad-hoc.

My question is, are there any functionals which will give reasonable values for the atomic ionisation potentials? I do not want to implement methods like the optimised effective potential method since the latter is not readily generalised to a finite-temperature scenario. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing which is wrong is that you somehow misinterpret the fact that DFT, as you said, *can* be quite accurate. Yes, it can, but it is *not* guaranteed to. In general the accuracy of DFT depends on many factors, but for prediction of -IP by HOMO eigenvalues it is well known that DFT performs rather *poorly*: absolute errors of few eVs are in fact quite *usual*.

Comment: See, e.g. [this paper](http://www.unige.ch/sciences/chifi/wesolowski/public_html/dft_epfl_2007/opt_failures/jpca_2007_111_1554.pdf) and references there in.

Comment: Thanks for the paper. Very informative indeed. It seems that KMLYP is best from the point of view of conformance to Koopmans' theorem. You are right; absolute errors of a few eVs are in fact quite usual.

Comment: http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.90.075135

Answer (score 5):

I think the most widely-used approach at the moment comes from Roi Baer and Leeor Kronik and others, e.g.

- [*Phys. Rev. Lett.* (2010) 105, art. 266802](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.105.266802)
- [*Phys. Rev. B* (2011) 84, art. 075144](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.84.075144)

Basically the idea is to tune the range-separation parameter $\gamma$ between short-range and long-range electrostatic effects in a range-separated hybrid functional. You find a match such that Koopmans' theorem holds.

The result is an "optimally-tuned" range-separated hybrid DFT functional (OT-RSH).

It's not perfect, for example, it violates size consistency: [*J. Chem. Phys.* (2013) 138, 204115](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4807325)

Comment: Have yet to read the paper. But from what you said, "You find a match such that Koopmans' theorem holds", it seems that the method is even more computationally intensive than the original, naive DFT. (For each potential obtain the self-consistent solutions (for both the atom and the ion?); for each pair of solutions, compute the ionization potential, and the energy of the highest occupied orbital (of the atom); if the two do not agree, tune the parameter; otherwise stop.)

Comment: This may be true in general, but it seems that for comparisons across related molecules, one can find a reasonable $\gamma$. The authors probably cringe at that suggestion, but errors ~ 0.1 eV for an intermediary parameter in the second paper, if I remember correctly.

Comment: My other comment is that Koopmans' theorem may not always hold in absolute terms, but there's usually a linear correlation between eigenvalues and ionization potentials with low residual errors.